# Proper way to use variables in awk in a script?

Tags: awk

I am learning awk. I'm confused on how to pass variables to awk in a script. Following the advice at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html I did (note the $ in front of `$'$line'`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
line=${1:-1}
git status -s | awk 'FNR == $'$line' {print $2}'
```

After some hair pulling, I got this to work by removing the first dollar sign in front of `$line`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
line=${1:-1}
git status -s | awk 'FNR == '$line' {print $2}'
```

So is the tutorial wrong or is there something about the behavior of variables outside of brackets that is different from those inside?

Comment: Take a look at awk's option -v.

Comment: The tutorial isn't exactly wrong since what you are trying to do is possible given a bunch of caveats but you should only do that in **extremely** rare circumstances. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for more info.